# How to wait for JQUERY AJAX response before choosing condition

Tags: jquery, ajax, return

```
$("#submit").click(function () {
    var boolError = false;

    CheckForm("#email");
    CheckPhone("#phone");

    if (boolError == true) {
        console.log('error');
    } else {
        console.log('here');
        // $("#form").submit();
    }
});
```

Problem is that it always returns `console.log('here');`

Is there a way to wait for CheckForm and CheckPhone. AJAX call from CheckForm function:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/webservice/user.asmx/CheckForm",
    data: "{'type':'" + var_type + "', 'value':'" + var_value + "'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { },
    success: function (data) {
        var obj = data.d;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

<strike>Try setting `async` to false:</strike> (**See edit below**)

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    url: "/webservice/user.asmx/CheckForm",
    data: "{'type':'" + var_type + "', 'value':'" + var_value + "'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { },
    success: function (data) {
        var obj = data.d;
    }
});
```

This will make the AJAX call blocking so the browser will wait for it to finish before continuing.  Of course, I'm still not sure how that relates back to the boolean being checked in the parent conditional.  Maybe there's code you're not showing us...

---

**Edit:** :::sigh::: I was young and foolish when I posted this answer, and in fact had forgotten all about it.  I'm keeping the above information unchanged for historical purposes (since it seems to have helped some people, or at least they think it has), but understand that this is ***not a correct approach***.

Making asynchronous calls synchronous and blocking execution is in every way incorrect.  Don't do it.  Instead, structure the logic to respond to the asynchronous operations.  In the case of this question, calls to `console.log()` should be happening in the success (or error) handler of the AJAX call, not in the code after the invocation of that call.

Answer (score 8):

You have to do this in the callback from the ajax call -- like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/webservice/user.asmx/CheckForm",
    data: "{'type':'" + var_type + "', 'value':'" + var_value + "'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log('error');
    },
    success: function (data) {
      console.log('here');
    }
});
```

Using AJAX requires non-linear programming -- callbacks abound.

You could set the option in the ajax call that makes it not async (ie jQuery will wait for it to finish) but this will make your application/web site not perform as well.

Comment: Correct. Using callbacks is a must when programming JavaScript & AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you put the conditional inside the success function.

```
 success: function (data) { if (...) { } else { }         

var obj = data.d;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

where u set `boolError=true`?? dats why it is always returning **here**;

u must change the logic like this in **checkForm**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { boolError==true;},
    success: function (data) {
        var obj = data.d;
    }
});
```